# Custom Site Content Types

Tags: content-type

I am trying to create a custom site content type for a calendar (list). I know the exact fields that I need for it, but I am not able to hide or disable the following columns:

Recurrence, All Day Event, Workspace

Is there a way to build a custom site content type without interference from pre-built content types?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately No, you must select `Parent Content Type` for each new site content type.

Regarding hiding `Recurrence` and `All Day Event` columns, you alright theses fields is not clickable in event content type setting to change its site columns setting to `Hidden (Will not appear in forms)`.

Meanwhile, to achieve your goal to hide Recurrence and All Day Event fields you can use jquery in script editor in your new and edit page as the following:

- Open your new item page in new tab.
- Edit the page > add script editor.
- Add the following code

**Code**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('nobr:contains("All Day Event")').closest('tr').hide();
$('nobr:contains("Recurrence")').closest('tr').hide();
});
</script>
```